# JavaScript - unable to create table using sequelize .create function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

At the top of the file, I have `const Sequelize = require('sequelize')`. After this, I did `sequelize.authenticate()`, and connection to database works. Then I have this to define my department table:

```
var Department = sequelize.define('Department', {
    departmentId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    departmentName: Sequelize.STRING,
    }, {
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false
})
```

Then, I had `sequelize.sync()` which works. But when I try to create table:

```
module.exports.addDepartment = function(departmentData)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        for (var i in departmentData)
        {
            if (departmentData[i] == "")
                departmentData[i] = null
        }

        Department.create(
            {
                departmentId: departmentData.departmentId,
                departmentName: departmentData.departmentName
            }
        ).then(() => { 
            resolve() 
        }).catch(() => { 
            reject("unable to create department") 
        })
    })
}
```

It doesn't work. I made sure that `departmentData.departmentName` has a value and `departmentData.departmentId` is null. No matter what I try, this is what it prints on my console:

> Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Departments" ("departmentId"  SERIAL , "departmentName" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("departmentId"));
>   Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as
>   column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Departments' GROUP BY
>   i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
>   Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Departments" ("departmentId","departmentName") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Creative Services') RETURNING *;
>   unable to create department

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have any suggestion as to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: `departmentId: departmentData.departmentId,` remove this from create and try again.

Comment: Isn't DepartmentId your PrimaryKey? Why are you passing `null` to a primary key?